# Why isn't my mutator function setting anything? Or my constructor?

Tags: c++, getter-setter

I'm trying to make a fairly basic program but I'm getting some very inconsistent outputs. In particular the setter doesn't seem to be setting values, although when I mess with the argument variables in ways which shouldn't alter the output I'm sometimes getting working results.

Here is my code:

### point.cpp

```
public:

point()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
point(double x, double y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
void set_x(double x)
{
    x = x;
}
void set_y(double y)
{
    y = y;
}
double get_x() const
{
    return x;
}
double get_y() const
{
    return y;
}
private:
double x;
double y;
};
```

### Main

```
point pointA;
double x,y;

cout << "Enter x value for point A: " << endl;
cin >> x;
pointA.set_x(x);
cout << "Enter y value for point A: " << endl;
cin >> y;
pointA.set_y(y);

point pointB(x,y);

cout << "X value for point A is: " << pointA.get_x() << endl;
cout << "Y value for point A is: " << pointA.get_y() << endl;
cout << "X value for point B is: " << pointB.get_x() << endl;
cout << "Y value for point B is: " << pointB.get_y() << endl;
```

### Output:

```
X value for point A is: 10
Y value for point A is: 10
X value for point B is: 3.18463e-314
Y value for point B is: 2.12199e-314
```

I'm really confused about all this since essentially the same functions are working in other similarly basic programs. If anyone could point out what obvious mistake I'm making it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because your function parameters are shadowing the member variables (and most compilers will warn you about that), either use `this->x` etc or rename your function parameters. Also for the constructor you should use member initializer lists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Change your  parameter names to px, py

Comment: I've tried changing the parameter names but I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: I personally am a fan of prefixing member variables with "m" or "m_". Makes it easy to distinguish between members and parameters.
In this case "int mX;" or "int m_x;"

Comment: @p.chives Just as an FYI, you've skipped code such as `class point` and your actual declaration of `main`. You should avoid self-editing that, because there might be something you've omitted that is causing the problem. Also, if you show code here that can be compiled without making any guesses as to what is missing, then it is easier for someone to verify your results. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

Let's examine one constructor, though the problem is the same everywhere

```
point(double x, double y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
```

`x` refers to to the **parameter**. So you are assigning the parameter to itself. Two and a half solutions are possible:

1. Use different names for the members and parameters.
2. Explicitly name the member with `this`, i.e. `this->x = x;`.
3. For the c'tor only. Use a member initializer list, `point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}`. Here there are special rules about what `x` is being referred to inside and outside the initializer. I recommend you use a member initializer list even if you adopt one of the previous solutions. It's more idiomatic C++.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will make use of member intitialisers from now on. However unfortunately even with option 1 I'm still getting the same result. If it was just a matter of definitions it should otherwise work now, right?

Comment: @p.chives - Are you sure you rebuilt your executable after making those changes? I for one, cannot reproduce your issue when the names are different. Also, if you intend to contribute on [so], you should know that changing an answer in a way that completely invalidates existing answers is poor netiquette 'round here.

Comment: @p.chives Be aware that you sometimes even are forced to use the initialiser list, e. g. for member variables of reference type, const members or of types with no assignment operators (i. e. no explicit ones and the default ones deleted)...

Comment: @StoryTeller I just rebuilt it again and it works fine now. I think I have an issue with my compiler since I hadn't changed anything since it started working.

Comment: @p.chives - Since it was a simple mistake I rolled back your changes to the question. The answer should fit the original question.

Comment: @StoryTeller It also wasn't my intention to invalidate previous answers. My logic was that making the change didn't improve the program and that people would continue to highlight it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @p.chives - I understand that. Which is why I didn't rollback immediately. Since you confirmed it was a compiler issue, and that the original question can stand, I rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem - as stated already by others - is that your member variable has the same name as the parameter.

Take a look at this method by itself. It is complete and does assign `x` to itself.

```
void set_x(double x)
{
    x = x;
}
```

In your code this `double x` hides the external (from the functions point of view) variable `x`.

I would recommend to prefix you member variables with `m_` or `m` (m for member).
This would make for unique names and help you distinguish and prevent such problems.

```
void set_x(double x)
{
    m_x = x;
}
```

Now you can see that the parameter `x` is assigned to the member variable `m_x`.

Alternatively you can also refer to the member with the same name by using the this-Pointer like this:

```
void set_x(double x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
```